# How can I change the text of a button at runtime on Android?

Tags: android, button

I want to write a simple example where I can change the text of a button at run time.

Basically, I am extracting the text from "EditText" view and trying to populate the contents of the button "OnClick" event.

However, the system crashes.

```
/** Called when the user clicks the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // Do something in response to button

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_message);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    btn.setText(message);

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

a) Should I be registering an Listener on the button for this purpose?
b) Is this another "Activity" and should I be creating an Intent for this?

Comment: Post the error log from logcat.

Comment: Is the `sendMessage` something you have declared as the `onClick` attribute in the XML?

Answer (score 0):

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_message);
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);

btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {  
       String message = editText.getText().toString();
       btn.setText(message);
    }
});
```

Inside the onclick events u get the string from edittext and set it to the button it will work